# Why does it write: unorderable types: int() < NoneType()?

Tags: python, recursion, binary-search-tree

I got for homework recursive version of Binary Search Tree and I have to insert numbers from array to BST and then search through it find if the number is there (True) or not (False).

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self, value, left, right):
        self.left = left
        self.right = right
        self.data = value

class BinarySearchTree:
    def __init__(self):
        self.root = Node(None, None, None)

    def insert(self, value):
        root = self.root
        new_node = Node(value, None, None)
        if root.data is None:
            root = new_node
        if new_node.data < root.data:
            if root.left is None:
                root.left = new_node
            else:
                root.left.insert(value)
                root = root.left
        else:
            if root.right is None:
                root.right = new_node
            else:
                root.right.insert(value)
                root = root.right

    def fromArray(self, array):
        for i in range(len(array)-1):
            value = array[i]
            BinarySearchTree.insert(self, value)
            i += 1
        return BinarySearchTree

    def search(self, value):
        if (self.root is not None):
            return self._search(value, self.root)
        else:
            return None

    def _search(self, value, node):
        new_node = Node(value, None, None)
        if (new_node.data == node.data):
            return True
        elif (new_node.data < node.data and node.left is not None):
            self._search(value, node.left)
        elif (new_node.data > node.data and node.right is not None):
            self._search(value, node.right)
        else:
            return False

    def min(self):
        root = self.root
        if root.left is None:
            return root
        else:
            self.min(root.left)

    def max(self):
        root = self.root
        if root.right is None:
            return root
        else:
            self.max(root.right)
```

And even tho I'm comparing two Nodes it writes error:

> unorderable types: int() < NoneType()

what is wrong?

Comment: Wherever you used `int()` there is no values in the variable you gave.

Comment: You need to return the results of your recursive calls.

Comment: always put full error message (Traceback) in question (as text, not screenshot). There are other useful informations.

Comment: it seems you try compare ie. `1 < None` . You have to check variables and don't compare them if one of them is `None`

Comment: At first it inserts numbers from arry and then it calls functions, should I return self or BinarySearchTree?